# No funciona método POST con <select>

Tags: php, html

He estado desarrollando un aplicativo para consultar una base de datos, necesito obtener los datos almacenados en un select que se auto rellena con datos seleccionados por el ususario, pero el php que llama al select con POST da error de índice.

Ya intenté dándole opciones fijas al select para probar pero tampoco funciona.

```html
<form id="main-form" name="main-form" method="POST" action="guardar_cot.php">
  <select form="main-form" multiple="multiple" id="seleccion" name="seleccion" size ="6"></select>

  <input type="submit" value="Guardar"> 
</form>
```

guardar_cot.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
            $save=$_POST["seleccion"];
            echo $save;
        ?>

    </body>
</html>`
```

Actualizado: Código javascript para el llenado del select

```js
function add_equipo(){
$("#Selecciona_Equipo option:selected").each(function(){
 ref_eq=$(this).val();
 $.post("includes/add_equipo.php", { ref_eq: ref_eq}, function(data){
      $("#seleccion").append(data);
     });
    });
}
```

add_equipo.php

```html
    <?php
  require('../conect-bd.php');
  $ref_eq = $_POST['ref_eq'];
  $equiposSelQ = "SELECT Nombre_Equipo, Ref FROM equipos WHERE Ref ='$ref_eq'";
  $resultadoA_E=$conexion->query($equiposSelQ);


  while ($row = $resultadoA_E->fetch_assoc()){  
    $html= "<option value='".$row['Ref']."'>".$row['Nombre_Equipo']."</option>"; 
    //echo '.$row["Ref"].'>'.$row["Nombre_Equipo"].';
  }
  echo $html;
?>
```

**Resuelto:**

El problema era que los objetos del select no se seleccionaban al oprimir el botón de guardar, solucionado agregando una función js al boton a través del atributo onclick.

Agrego la fuente del código.
https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/JQuery/3012-Seleccionar-y-de-seleccionar-todos-los-elementos-de-un-select.html

Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Estás asignando un value a tus options? Un select vacío no tiene valor y por tanto no se pasa mediante POST.

Comment: estan en e la misma carpeta ?, haz probado solo dejando el codigo php y borrando el html completo?

Comment: Juliosor, el select se va llenando automáticamente al seleccionar ítems de una lista, tengo una función en js que lo actualiza a través de un script php así: "<option value='".$row['Ref']."'>".$row['Nombre_Equipo']."</option>"

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código javascript? Tal vez tengas ahí el error. ¿De donde salen los datos que insertas en los options?

Comment: Ya agregué el código

Comment: El select si se esta llenando?

Comment: Creo que ya se cual es el error que se te esta presentado, necesitas realizar un `var_dump($_POST['seleccion']);` y confirmame los datos que te muestra

Comment: ¿puedes visualizar las opciones del select? por que así a priori en el while estas guardando sólo el último option, con lo cual sólo imprimira uno

Comment: Sí el select se llena y todo se visualiza normal, incluso añadí un botón para quitar elementos y también funciona perfectamente

Comment: @Andrés sale lo siguiente:
 Notice: Undefined index: seleccion in E:\Software\wamp\www\ADC_Database\forms\guardar_cot.php on line 38

E:\Software\wamp\www\ADC_Database\forms\guardar_cot.php:38:null

Answer (score 2):

Estas utilizando un select múltiple

```
 <select form="main-form" multiple="multiple" id="seleccion" name="seleccion" size ="6">
```

Por lo que debes ponerle como nombre a tu select como un arreglo (seleccion[])

```
 <select form="main-form" multiple="multiple" id="seleccion" name="seleccion[]" size ="6">
```

Esto hará que cuando ejecutes tu formulario la variable $save contenga un arreglo con todos los elementos que seleccionaste en el select, para verificarlo puedes usar la siguiente función de php

```
var_dump($save);
```

Como algo adicional te aconsejo que verifiques que la variable super global $_POST contengan algo antes de intentar acceder a algún elemento

```
if($_POST) { //Mi codigo }
```

Ejemplo llenado del select con JSON

**PHP**

```
<?php
  require('../conect-bd.php');
  $ref_eq = $_POST['ref_eq'];
  $equiposSelQ = "SELECT Nombre_Equipo, Ref FROM equipos WHERE Ref ='$ref_eq'";
  $resultadoA_E=$conexion->query($equiposSelQ);

  $data = [];

  while ($row = $resultadoA_E->fetch_assoc()){  
    $data[$row["Ref"]] = $row["Nombre_equipo"]
  }
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  die(json_encode($data));
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.getJSON( "includes/add_equipo.php", function( data ) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $("#seleccion").append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sí, eso también lo había leído pero igual no funciona, arroja éste error:

Notice: Undefined index: seleccion in E:\Software\wamp\www\ADC_Database\forms\guardar_cot.php on line 39

E:\Software\wamp\www\ADC_Database\forms\guardar_cot.php:39:null

Comment: Asegurate igualmente que tu select no se este mal formando, me refiero a que las etiquetas se este imprimiendo mal en el momento que agregas tus options al select, lo digo por que se me hace un poco extraña la forma en que lo haces, yo te aconsejaría que mejor usaras JSON para transferir información entre PHP y javascript, puedes verificar la estructura de tu select con la consola de tu navegador

Comment: Vale, voy a intentarlo, igualmente ya le dí opciones fijas al select y el var_dump arroja: null

Answer (score -2):

prueba con esto a ver si te funciona

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
           if (isset($_POST['guardar'])){
               $save=$_POST["seleccion"];
               echo $save;
            }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>`
```

html

```
 <form id="main-form" name="main-form" method="POST" action="guardar_cot.php">
  <select form="main-form" multiple="multiple" id="seleccion" name="seleccion" size ="6"></select>

  <input type="submit" id="guardar" name="guardar" value="Guardar"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Hola Miguel. Pegar un codigo sin más no se consdiera de calidad. Has de explicar qué problema hay con el codigo del OP y cómo tu respuesta funciona . Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: No, tampoco funciona

Comment: ok primero te falta el tab option dentro del select para seleccionar una opcion  y con el post debería tomar la variable que elegiste Ejemplo  <select form="main-form" multiple="multiple" id="seleccion" name="seleccion" size ="6">
            <option>prueba</option>
          </select>

Comment: Añade la información a la respuesta, no en los comentarios

Answer (score -5):

Intenta cambiar tu código PHP por:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['seleccion'])){
             $save=$_POST['seleccion'];
        }
        echo $save;
    ?>
```

Comment: Hola Dacevid. Pegar un codigo sin más no se consdiera de calidad. Has de explicar qué problema hay con el codigo del OP y cómo tu respuesta funciona . Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Sí eso ya lo intenté y pues nunca entra al if